# How much special yeast do I need?

Tags: ingredients

I have seen this particular beverage and I want to brew this at home. How much fluid yeast do I need to collect to make 1 gallon of this particular high end brew? How do test for yeast content?

http://orderyoni.com/
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The yeast is not what is special, it is naturally produced lactobacillus bacteria from the vagina. The beer is classified as a sour ale, and to culture this bacteria you would need to collect a sample and grow it in a aseptic environment to ensure your product will turn out as you want. This will be very difficult with out proper lab training or equipment. You could however inoculate some wort with this lactobacillus just from swabbing and placing the swab in a starter to give a rudimentary lactic acid source to sour the beer. I would not recommend doing this in your standard brewing equipment. 
Good Luck
Cheers